# How to store all edittext value in array list

Tags: android, arraylist, android-edittext

I want to store my every edittext value in an arraylist but right now my arraylist is storing only the last value that I entered in edittext.I want to store all the values that I entered in edittext into this array list.My code is as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(mycartonno.getText().toString());
```

Comment: In which method have you written this code?

Comment: may be you are creating arraylist object everytime. you have to create its object once.

Comment: assign new value to array list at onCreate method of at global then add data from edittext to array on some action perfomed you can see that the new data to the array list is stored to new index.

Comment: maybe the reason is 
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

make your list as global and declare it once.

Comment: I am using my code inside Edittext.setOnClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are creating **new ArrayList** on Every OnClick.

So create your **ArrayList** Globally/ Outside your onClick

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // define this is as globally

list.add(mycartonno.getText().toString());    // add this line to where you do your onclick like button
```

Comment: This worked for me.I used global arraylist like you said and I just changed my code too to add value inside arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use TextChangedListener to store your value every your changing your value.

```
EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {} 
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a TextWatcher.
Now depending on your requirement,call list.add(s) in any of the implemeted methods of OnTextChangedListener.

```
    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 

        {

                 @Override
                 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                  //use here if you want to save after a string is typed
                     list.add(s.toString());
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,          int after) {
//use here if you want to save before already present string is changed
                     list.add(s.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
        //use here if you want to save all the strings that are  typed
                     list.add(s.toString());
                }
                };);
```

Comment: This is not working and with this I am having the same above issue.I am getting only last entered edittext value inside arraylist.I want to store all the entered values of edittext inside arraylist